# use innerHTML to select class only if it is in a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, parent, innerhtml

i currently have the code below which searches for the class and will replace the text.

how would i tweak it so it only will replace text if the parent tag is "#thumb-hockey-top"?

```
window.onload = function(){
     //this captures all the elements with the spec classes
     var soldItems = document.getElementsByClassName('product-mark sold-out');

     //this changes each element 1 by 1 to new text
        for(var i=0; i<soldItems.length; i++){
           soldItems[i].innerHTML = "Coming Soon";
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use once**

```js
window.onload = function(){
     //this captures all the elements with the spec classes
     var soldItems = document.getElementById("thumb-hockey-top").getElementsByClassName('product-mark sold-out');

     //this changes each element 1 by 1 to new text
        for(var i=0; i<soldItems.length; i++){
          soldItems[i].innerHTML = "Coming Soon"
        }

}
```

```html
<div id="thumb-hockey-top">
  <div class="product-mark sold-out"></div>
</div>
<div class="product-mark sold-out"></div>
<div class="product-mark sold-out"></div>
```

**Use multiple times**

```js
function myF(a, b){
  // a = Id of parent element
  // b = Class Name of element which you want to hack
  var soldItems = document.getElementById(a).getElementsByClassName(b);

  for(var i=0; i<soldItems.length; i++){
    soldItems[i].innerHTML = "Coming Soon"
  }
}
myF("thumb-hockey-top", "product-mark sold-out");
myF("thumb-hockey-bottom", "product-unmark sold-out");
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <div id="thumb-hockey-top">
    <div class="product-mark sold-out">EXAMPLE 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-mark sold-out">EXAMPLE 1</div>
</div>

<div class="example2">
  <div id="thumb-hockey-bottom">
    <div class="product-unmark sold-out">EXAMPLE 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-unmark sold-out">EXAMPLE 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much! if i wanted to have this apply to two different part, ie run two times, would i just duplicate the function and change the var names? or something else?

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  //this captures all the elements with the spec classes
  //just use a class
  var soldItems = document.getElementsByClassName('sold-out');
  //this changes each element 1 by 1 to new text
  //var parentnode = document.getElementById('thumb-hockey-top') 
    for(var i=0; i<soldItems.length; i++){
      if(soldItems[i].parentNode.id=='thumb-hockey-top'){
         soldItems[i].innerHTML = "Coming Soon";
      }
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="thumb-hockey-top">
    <div class="product-mark sold-out"></div>
    <div class="product-mark sold-out"></div>
    <div class="product-mark sold-out"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent element of an element using the parentElement attribute. Then just check its id.

```
var soldItem = soldItems[i];
if (soldItem.parentElement.id == "thumb-hockey-top") {
    // do your thing
}
```